# PowerDNS error with slave

Tags: powerdns, slave, master

I have a PowerDNS 3.3 server installed on Ubuntu 14.04 (for testing).
It should be master only. No slave exists.

I keep on getting this error:

```
Received NOTIFY for mydomain.com from 82.91.23.176 but slave support is disabled in the configuration
Received unsuccessful notification report for 'mydomain.com' from 82.91.23.176:53, rcode: 4
```

`82.91.23.176` (modified in this post) is the WAN IP of the PowerDNS server.

Here my pdns.conf

```
allow-axfr-ips=127.0.0.1
allow-recursion=127.0.0.1
config-dir=/etc/powerdns
daemon=yes
disable-axfr=no
guardian=yes
include-dir=/etc/powerdns/pdns.d
local-address=0.0.0.0
local-port=53
master=yes
module-dir=/usr/lib/powerdns
setgid=pdns
setuid=pdns
socket-dir=/var/run
version-string=powerdns
webserver=yes
webserver-address=192.168.178.33
```

To my understanding, `slave=no` is per default and no slave is allowed for axfr, so PowerDNS should not receive any notification at all.

Or what is this message about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have set `master=yes` which tells PowerDNS to send notifications. It does not check sent notifications against the `allow-axfr-ips` list because transfers might not come from the notified IPs.

If you want the `NOTIFY` to go away, set `master=no`.

Comment: Yes, that worked (thanks!), though I don't really understand it. Very hard to find basic PowerDNS FAQs/TOWTOs explaining basic mechanisms (while DNS basics are known).

Comment: Also ...  (1.) PowerDNS seems to self-notify. Why is this? (2.) Self-notification can be disabled by `prevent-self-notification`. This seems to work. If master/slave configuration is used, `master=yes` must be set. Hence your suggestion would not work in this case.

Comment: I got a bit further. The point is that the master server notifies itself, which should be avoided. I need master enabled since I would like to install at least 1 slave server later on. So `master=yes` will be set, triggering again the mentions warnings. The bottom line is that I need to know how PowerDNS tries to avoid this self-notification. `prevent-self-notification=yes` doesn't do it! I could not find any documentation about this subject (Google), but quite a lot of postings around 2013 that it will be fixed. So ... how do the PowerDNS mechanisms work to avoid self-notification!

Comment: Avoiding self notification is hard in some network setups. You have not described yours so I cannot usefully comment. You could also decide to just ignore the messages!

Comment: On a sidenote, I see you are trying to post to the PowerDNS pdns-users mailing list via Nabble. This no longer works, as clearly marked on Nabble. If you want to post to the mailing list, please subscribe to it and send an actual email.

Comment: (Nabble) ... uuhh ... it worked so far. Gonna check this. The PowerDNS Links still points to Nabble.
https://www.powerdns.com/mailing-lists.html
http://powerdns.13854.n7.nabble.com/

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, I have removed the link.